# Tuple of tuples as argparse command line argument

Tags: python

I need users to provide a list of lists of numbers as command line arguments.

The current solution I'm adopting is here below, the question is whether there is a more pythonic or more standard way of doing it.

Currently I'm accepting a comma-separated list of space-separated numbers from command line, like this:

```
$ python foo.py --numbers '1 2 3, 4 5 6'
```

and internally I do

```
def list_of_lists(arg):
    return map(lambda l: map(float, l), map(str.split, a.split(',')))

parser.add_argument('--numbers', type=list_of_lists)
```

to transform the string `"1 2 3, 4 5 6"` into `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

Comment: I'd use a format that is easily and safely (de)serializable, like JSON.

Comment: you can use sys library. then ask the users to input the data in the following form: 1,2,3 4,5,6 7,8,9. The space separated values are combined into list as one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is fine. If I were writing it, I'd use commas and semicolons as delimiters (being strict about it: no whitespace allowed), and use a list comprehension for parsing:

```
def list_of_lists(arg):
    return [float(x.split(',')) for x in arg.split(';')]
```

but that's really just cosmetic.

The next question is: how much verification do you want to do in `list_of_lists`? Right now, this simple version assumes that the string is in exactly the format you want. You can add more logic to catch errors, raising `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` to signal incorrect values.

Comment: nice, list comprehension is much nicer than those nested `map` calls I was making. commas and semicolons vs spaces and commas I have to try and see what looks nicer. thank you!

Comment: p.s. the final list comprehension looks like this: `[[float(x) for x in l.split(',')] for l in arg.split(';')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`action="append"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) and use `--numbers` more than once.

> This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times.

```
import argparse

def to_list(arg):
    return [int(i) for i in arg.split(",")]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--numbers", action="append", type=to_list)
parsed = parser.parse_args("--numbers 1,2,3 --numbers 4,5,6".split())
print(parsed)
```

Output:

```
Namespace(numbers=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```